# How can I dynamically wire a Starling view with Parsley MVC IOC injection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, fdt, parsley, starling-framework

I am using Starling with in a Flex app. The app is using Parsley framework and doing IOC on the views.

Starling is of corse not a regular Flash displayobject. Normally within a Parsley project if I want to dynamically inject when a view is created I will just call Configure.view(this).execute() and all is well.

I'm wondering if there is a way to inject data models dynamically into my Starling view without using Configure.view sense starling view is not a DisplayObject in the normal flash display list.

Answer (score 3):

Well about an hour after I posted this question I found this solution by talking to Patrick Kulling who used to work for powerflasher / FDT and knows Parsley inside and out.

Basically you have to get an instance of the Parsley Context and and then call context.addDynamicObject like so.

```
            [Inject]
            public var context:Context;

            [Init]
            private function onImagesReady( event : Event = null ) : void
            {
                     //star.root gives us a ref to MainGame witch is our starling view    
                    //that want parsley to do IOC on
                 context.addDynamicObject(star.root);
            }


                    //here is where we call the starling code and it creates an instance
            private function onCC() : void
            {
                star = new Starling( MainGame, stage );
                star.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                star.start();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [parsley-starling](https://github.com/rozdonmobile/parsley-starling) library that adopts Parsley for using with Starling.

It based on [modified version of Parsley](https://github.com/rozdonmobile/parsley-core), that is less dependent on Flash API.

After libraries are linked, you add `StarlingViewManagerDecorator` when creating your Context:

```
ContextBuilder.newSetup()
    .services()
        .viewManager()
            .addDecorator(StarlingViewManagerDecorator, _starling)
    .newBuilder()
        .config(XmlConfig.forFile("config.xml"))
    .build();
```

after that use `StarlingConfigure` class for Starling's DisplayObject to make it managed:

```
import feathers.controls.Screen
public class NewsView extends Screen
{
    public function NewsView()
    {
        super();

        StarlingConfigure.view(this).execute();
    }
}
```